# Chromedriver wont open google chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Basically I just started a tutorial and am using chromedriver and selenium for the first time. It seems that the code in the tutorial opens chrome but for me it just runs, doesn't give any errors and finishes without opening chrome. What am I missing?

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\\users\\flaviamadau\\desktop\\schoolpython\\chromedriver.exe"

wd = webdriver
```

and after running

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

*edit

a comment said I needed to add

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
```

after adding this I get errors saying the following

```
/Users/flaviamadau/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectuva/bin/python /Users/flaviamadau/Desktop/SchoolPython/PythonUVA/Webscrape.py
/Users/flaviamadau/Desktop/SchoolPython/PythonUVA/Webscrape.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/flaviamadau/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectuva/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\users\\flaviamadau\\desktop\\schoolpython\\chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/flaviamadau/Desktop/SchoolPython/PythonUVA/Webscrape.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
  File "/Users/flaviamadau/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectuva/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/Users/flaviamadau/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectuva/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/flaviamadau/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectuva/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'C:\users\flaviamadau\desktop\schoolpython\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

basically no improvement

Comment: you need "driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)"

Comment: So how would I integrate that in my current code as I'm a total beginner

Comment: Just put whats in quotes as another line and a window should open when you run it.

Comment: i added the line, check the new error in the post

Comment: All that means is that the path to your chromedriver is wrong.
Check that it is definitely in: "C:\users\flaviamadau\desktop\schoolpython\chromedriver.exe"
Or, if you havent already, add it to your path in the first place.
Check out the video for how to do that if you havent: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz59GsdvUF8

Comment: Youre the best mate, was a pathing issue very simple stuff I overlooked :/